# Best Practice for Product Names with many dimensions

Tags: e-commerce, seo, product-management

I have read this related question: [Best Practice for product titles with dimensions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82768/best-practice-for-product-titles-with-dimensions), but I felt it didn't deal with complex cases.

My products broadly fall under "Construction Supplies" and as such have various dimensions that describe their fittings, with only a generic name that describes the product.

Some examples below:

**Products with simple dimensions:**

> 5/8 inch x 14 inch Machine Bolt

**Products with dimension and two measurement standards:**

> 1 1/2 inch Double E Loc- 1.90in OD - 1.5in IPS

**Products with related measurement, plus SKU unit of measure:**

> Cable Pulling Tape 2500lb - 5000ft
>
> 9/16 inch Python Rod - 900 feet

**Products with dimensions for separate parts:**

> 1.50 inch Replacement Plow Blade Carbide Reamer 0.76 inch Shank
>
> 1.75 inch Replacement Plow Blade Carbide Reamer 0.76 inch Shank

When should Fractions vs Decimals be used? Or should it just be consistent?

Should "inch" be spelled out or abbreviated?

The guidelines I've read (including Amazon and the [referenced question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82768/best-practice-for-product-titles-with-dimensions) generally suggest including specific details, like dimensions, last. However for products like the Pulling Tape, there are two measurements: the pulling strength (in pounds) of the tape, plus the length for this SKU. What is the best way to format this?

Comment: Are you naming them for your own site or is it for posting for sale on other sites?

Comment: This is for our own site

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, make it consistent. Do not mix up units of measurement, naming conventions (in - inch etc).

If you think about the type of customer that will be browsing your site, they will be more interested in the specifics and measurements of the name of the item. Of course the name is needed as it contains brands and an indication to its use but make sure that the details are clearly marked out in your product description.

Answer (score 0):

If all of these product names appear on the same webpage you could consider grouping/categorizing.
Then you could align the attributes and give some space between each unit and the description to improve readability and comparability.

However, it is not advised to change the way units are read. If people know it a certain way, meaning they spell "one and a half" (1 1/2) inch and you display "one point five" (1.5) inch then they might be confused.
And if they personally do not know, most probably the one who they trust knows it one way or the other. These things are fixed by those who operate them. Do not change their jargon.

Also, consider the feature to provide alternative ways of displaying the units. For example, some people would beg you to convert inches to mm because they are used in another metric system. This could be vital or not depending on the audience.

From the information in the question, it seems that the only purpose of the product names it to "make sure that we are buying the exact right thing that we need and nothing similar". If this is true then the user should not be afraid of putting in the basket similar items, therefore proper distances must be kept between clickable items etc.